# What does this function expect to return?

Tags: c++

Program specifies the following:

1. Write a program with total change amount as an integer input that outputs the change using the fewest coins, one coin type per line.
2. The coin types are dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies.
3. Use singular and plural coin names as appropriate, like 1 penny vs. 2 pennies.
4. Your program must define and call the following function.
   void ExactChange(int userTotal, vector& coinVals)
5. Positions 0-4 of coinVals should contain the number of dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies, respectively.

My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
/*
 1) Write a program with total change amount as an integer input that outputs the change using the fewest coins, one coin type per line.
 2) The coin types are dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies.
 3) Use singular and plural coin names as appropriate, like 1 penny vs. 2 pennies.
 
 4) Your program must define and call the following function.
            void ExactChange(int userTotal, vector<int>& coinVals)
 
 5) Positions 0-4 of coinVals should contain the number of dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies, respectively.
 */
void ExactChange(int userTotal, vector<int>& coinVals);
const int PENNIES_IN_DOLLAR = 100, PENNIES_IN_QUARTER = 25, PENNIES_IN_DIME = 10, PENNIES_IN_NICKEL = 5;

int main() {
   int userTotal, changeRemaining;
   cin >> userTotal;
    changeRemaining = userTotal;
    
    int dollars = changeRemaining / PENNIES_IN_DOLLAR;
    changeRemaining = changeRemaining % PENNIES_IN_DOLLAR;
    int quarters = changeRemaining / PENNIES_IN_QUARTER;
    changeRemaining = changeRemaining % PENNIES_IN_QUARTER;
    int dimes = changeRemaining / PENNIES_IN_DIME;
    changeRemaining = changeRemaining % PENNIES_IN_DIME;
    int nickels = changeRemaining / PENNIES_IN_NICKEL;
    changeRemaining = changeRemaining % PENNIES_IN_NICKEL;
    int pennies = changeRemaining;
    
    vector<int> changeAmount;
    
    vector<int> coinVals{dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies};
    changeAmount = coinVals;
    ExactChange(userTotal, changeAmount);
    
  return 0;
}
void ExactChange(int userTotal, vector<int>& coinVals) {
    
    if (userTotal == 0) {
       cout << "no change" << endl;
    }
      if(coinVals.at(0) > 0) {
       cout << coinVals.at(0);
       if(coinVals.at(0) > 1) {
           cout << " dollars" << endl;
       }else {
           cout << " dollar" << endl;
       }
    }
    if(coinVals.at(1) > 0) {
       cout << coinVals.at(1);
       if(coinVals.at(1) > 1) {
           cout << " quarters" << endl;
       } else {
           cout << " quarter" << endl;
       }
    }
    if(coinVals.at(2) > 0) {
       cout << coinVals.at(2);
       if(coinVals.at(2) > 1) {
           cout << " dimes" << endl;
       }else {
           cout << " dime" << endl;
       }
    }
    if(coinVals.at(3) > 0) {
       cout << coinVals.at(3);
       if(coinVals.at(3) > 1) {
           cout << " nickels" << endl;
       }else {
           cout << " nickel" << endl;
       }
    }
    if(coinVals.at(4) > 0) {
       cout << coinVals.at(4);
       if(coinVals.at(4) > 1) {
           cout << " pennies" << endl;
       }else {
           cout << " penny" << endl;
       }
    }
}
```

However, zybooks, the site where our college course does our labs gives me these messages indicating some problem with my code:

[image]

**My question is, what do those "messages" mean? Any how could I fix the issues?** It seems to me they are saying the function is outputting something incorrectly given a certain input, however, they also don't give me a correct output to compare to.

Comment: If you have a development environment installed on a PC you can control  you should have access to a debugger. With the debugger you can load up the inputs you want to test and then step through the program looking for where the program does something unexpected and gets the math wrong. That'll be a bug. Then you figure out from the difference between what you wanted to happen and what happened what went wrong, and fix the program to do the right thing. The debugger will save you a ton of time on every assignment, so it's worth the little bit of time you'll spend figuring out how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is taking user input, converting it manually directly in `main()` before calling `ExactChange()`, and then passing the result of that conversion to `ExactChange()` for it to display *as-is*.

The way I read the instructions, and the way the screenshot shows the tests being performed, it is more likely that `ExactChange()` is expected to take user input and convert it onto a `vector` of coin amounts as output.

That would be consistent with the fact that `ExactChange()` takes a `vector` by **non-const reference**, which means it can freely modify the contents of the `vector`.  If `ExactChange()` were meant for text output, it would make more sense for it to take the `vector` by **const reference** instead, so that it can't *modify* the `vector`, only *view* it.

If so, then it makes sense that your program would pass tests that give it user-defined input and look for specific text results, but your program would fail tests that *execute `ExactChange()` directly* with specific inputs and look for specific `vector` outputs.  That is the whole point of *Unit Tests* - to test functions directly for expected behaviors, not test whole programs.

Your code likely needs to look more like the following instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

/*
 1) Write a program with total change amount as an integer input that outputs the change using the fewest coins, one coin type per line.
 2) The coin types are dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies.
 3) Use singular and plural coin names as appropriate, like 1 penny vs. 2 pennies.
 
 4) Your program must define and call the following function.
            void ExactChange(int userTotal, vector<int>& coinVals)
 
 5) Positions 0-4 of coinVals should contain the number of dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies, respectively.
 */

void ExactChange(int userTotal, vector<int>& coinVals);
const int PENNIES_IN_DOLLAR = 100, PENNIES_IN_QUARTER = 25, PENNIES_IN_DIME = 10, PENNIES_IN_NICKEL = 5;

int main() {
   int userTotal;
   cin >> userTotal;
        
   if (userTotal == 0) {
      cout << "no change" << endl;
   }
   else {
      vector<int> coinVals;
      ExactChange(userTotal, coinVals);

      if (coinVals[0] > 0) {
         cout << coinVals[0];
         if (coinVals[0] > 1) {
            cout << " dollars" << endl;
         } else {
            cout << " dollar" << endl;
         }
      }

      if (coinVals[1] > 0) {
         cout << coinVals[1];
         if (coinVals[1] > 1) {
            cout << " quarters" << endl;
         } else {
            cout << " quarter" << endl;
         }
      }

      if (coinVals.at(2) > 0) {
         cout << coinVals[2];
         if (coinVals[2] > 1) {
            cout << " dimes" << endl;
         }else {
            cout << " dime" << endl;
         }
      }

      if (coinVals[3] > 0) {
         cout << coinVals[3];
         if (coinVals[3] > 1) {
            cout << " nickels" << endl;
         }else {
            cout << " nickel" << endl;
         }
      }

      if (coinVals[4] > 0) {
         cout << coinVals[4];
         if (coinVals[4] > 1) {
            cout << " pennies" << endl;
         }else {
            cout << " penny" << endl;
         }
      }
   }

   return 0;
}

void ExactChange(int userTotal, vector<int>& coinVals) {    
    int dollars = userTotal / PENNIES_IN_DOLLAR;
    userTotal %= PENNIES_IN_DOLLAR;
    int quarters = userTotal / PENNIES_IN_QUARTER;
    userTotal %= PENNIES_IN_QUARTER;
    int dimes = userTotal / PENNIES_IN_DIME;
    userTotal %= PENNIES_IN_DIME;
    int nickels = userTotal / PENNIES_IN_NICKEL;
    userTotal %= PENNIES_IN_NICKEL;
    int pennies = userTotal;
    
    coinVals.resize(5);
    coinVals[0] = dollars;
    coinVals[1] = quarters;
    coinVals[2] = dimes;
    coinVals[3] = nickels;
    coinVals[4] = pennies;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps explain that this is why `coinVals` is passed by reference.

Comment: @Barmar I added it

Comment: It seems the reason I had trouble is because I'm generally having trouble grasping the pass by reference concept as well as the fact that in our college class we haven't studied vectors at all before having to do this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Remy. An easier way of saying it would be that Zybooks sets the size for the vector as you open the section:

```
vector<int> changeAmount(5);
```

To pass the two problems, instead of clearing out the (5) or push_back'ing the amounts (which is 100% what I originally did), you just need to point the coin amount to the already created vector index directly.

Your code did this:

```
vector<int> coinVals{dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies};
    changeAmount = coinVals;
```

When all you needed to do for each amount was:

```
coinVals.at(3) = dollars;
```

Because the vector is pass by reference (that '&' right before the vector name), your updates to the vector will be carried back through to your main function.

Thanks for posting! This thread helped me solve this one as well!